# Existing Port running on starting Postgres App(MacOS)

Tags: postgresql

After restart/shutdown, my postgres App is saying that i'm already running on 5432 port, i am manually quitting those processes in Activity monitor and then starting postgres! How should i permanently shutdown that 5432 port and after shutdown or restart i should skip killing those processes in activity monitor and start over.

I tried manually executing commands and killing those processes everytime..another server is using 5432 port

Comment: Did you check whether PostgreSQL or some other app are running as a service somewhere? Service management tools tend to restart the application in case of interruptions.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @GustavoKawamoto no the service launches automatically at startup and no other app is using it.. Thanks for your reply and i found the solution for it! the problem was  resolved after deleting  Postgres15.plist in path /Library/LanchDaemons